# How to combine post and session value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering is how to combine a (session) and (post) value to make a (title)value.

```
$position = $_POST['position'];
$division = $_POST['division'];
$title = $_SESSION['repcode'] +._.+ $_POST['position'];
```

I want is the outcome of the title would be

example output:

title = rep230_manager

how to do this?

Comment: concatenation in php is the DOT ... not ++++. this is not javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$title = $_SESSION['repcode'].'_'. $_POST['position'];
```

Comment: to be fair you should mark the first posted correct answer in my opinion

Comment: your right, im sorry, im counting backwards today for some reason

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = $_SESSION['repcode'] . "_" . $_POST['position'];
```

Comment: ' are a few nanoseconds faster than "

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate string in PHP use . operator

```
$title = $_SESSION['repcode'] .'_'. $_POST['position'];
```

Also you can use " " or ' ' for concatenating. But ' ' will be few nanoseconds faster than " " as Double quotes execute the string but single quote doesn't so its faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also interpolate the variable values into the string if you find that easier

```
$title = "{$_SESSION['repcode']}_{$_POST['position']}";
```